# Separating an inputted integer into a list to check if each element of the list meets the requirements

Tags: python

```
input_list = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")

number = input_list.split()
for n in number:
     a = int(n)
if len(number)!=5 or number>5 or number<0 :
        print ('invalid input')
        if 0< a <=5:
            print ('x'* a)
        elif a == 0:
            print ('.')
```

My program is checking the 5 digits which are inputted as if they are one number but I want my program to first make sure that 5 digits are inputed and then check if they are between 0 and 5 but the program combines all 5 digits into one number, I want the program to check each element of the list on it's own and before printing anything I want the program to check if the inputted number meets all the conditions and if does not to print (Invalid Input) and stop their

Comment: The indentation is messed up. Also note that `number` is a list so doing `number > 5` cannot provide a meaningful result(and it results in a `TypeError` in python3!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
number = raw_input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")
2   num_list = number.split()
3   for n in num_list:
4       a = 'True'
5       if int(n) <0 or int(n) >5:
6           a = 'False'
7           break       
8   if (len(num_list) == 5) and a == 'True':
9       for n in num_list:
10          b = int(n)
11          if 0< b <=5:
12              print ('x'* b)
13          elif b == 0:
14              print ('.')
15  else:
16      print 'Invalid Input!'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input_list = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")

numbers = input_list.split()

if len(numbers) == 5 and all(0 <= int(n) <= 5 for n in numbers):
    print("ok")
    print("".join(numbers))
else:
    print("invalid")
```

Comment: It should be `0 <= int(n) <= 5`. Or make `numbers` a list of ints.

Answer (score 0):

I use raw_input in python 2. input is fine for python 3.

```
input_list = raw_input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ").split()
numbers = [int(n) for n in input_list if 0 <= int(n) <= 5]
if len(numbers) != 5:
    print ('invalid input')

for a in numbers:
    if a == 0:
        print ('.')
    else:
        print ('x'* a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces: ")

number = input_list.split()
if len(number) == 5:
    for n in number:
        a = int(n)
        if 0< a <=5:
            print ('x'* a)
        elif a == 0:
            print ('.')
        else:
            print ("Number does not lie in the range 0 to 5.")
else:
    print ("Invalid Input.")
Yes, the above works but is should check input first to make sure it is valid
```